# Is there a way to determine logstash input plugin from message?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

I have two (kafka) input plugins in my logstash config. Each input plugin is configured to listen to a different kafka broker.
I would like to include in the message some field that represents which input plugin generated the message.
I was hoping to be able to include a hard-coded field like "input=kafka1", "input=kafka2", etc. in my input definition.
I don't think I can use mutate filter because by that time, I don't know where the message came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`tags`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-tags) option in your inputs.

```
input {
    kafka {
        *** your first input config ***
        tags => ["kafka1"]
    }
    kafka {
        *** your second config ***
        tags => ["kafka2"]
    }
}
```

Then you can use those tags to filter in your `filter` block.

```
filter {
    if "kafka1" in [tags] {
        filters for kafka 1 tag
    }

    if "kafka2" in [tags] {
        filters for kafka 2 tag
    }
}
```

You can use the same conditionals in your `output` block.

You can also use [multiple pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html) and have a different pipeline for each kafka broker.

Comment: Thanks! So if I wanted to add the tag so that I can later query it in kibana, would I need to add a field using a mutate filter, or would it be already added?

Comment: If you add the `tags` in your input, the field `tags` will be in your document and you can use it to filter later on kibana, no need to add another field.